# Definition of atomic $\sigma$-field.

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, random-variables

Reading an article in probability theory I faced with phrase **atomic $\sigma$-field**. I tried to search for the definition, but google doesn't give any meaningful result. As a result I'm looking for the definition here.

Comment: can you link the article or quote the relevant portion? definition of atom(ic) for a **measure**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28measure_theory%29 my guess is that the $\sigma$-algebra must have at least one element that is not a null set and whose proper subsets are all null sets

Comment: I found that definition of atom, but here I'm looking for the definition of atomic $sigma-field$.

Comment: in the absence of a measure you could take the maximal ideal as the collection of null sets; or maybe they include the measure in the definition of $\sigma$-field... that's why you should quote the passage as it appears to be a nonstandard definition

Answer (score 4):

Absent the notion of a $\sigma$-ideal of null sets an atomic $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ has the property that for every $E\in \Sigma$ there is $E'\in \Sigma$ satisfying $E'\neq \emptyset$, $E'\subseteq E$, and if $E''\subseteq E'$, $E''\in \Sigma$, then $E'=\emptyset$.

If $\Sigma$ admits a strictly positive measure, then it contains a countable many atoms.

But without a strictly positive measure the algebra of Borel sets on $[0,1]$ is atomic but restricted to $(0,1]$ it is not.

Now suppose that $\mathcal{N}$ is a $\sigma$-ideal of $\Sigma$, then taking the quotient algebra $\mathcal{F}=\Sigma|_{\mathcal{N}}$ and ordering it by set inclusion. We say that $\mathcal{F}$ is atomic if every non-trivial chain in $\mathcal{F}$ has a second smallest element.

Comment: I think you have to change "then $E'=\emptyset$" to "then $E''=\emptyset$ or $E'=E''$".

Answer (score 4):

To expand on Rabee's answer, an *atom* in a measurable space is a nonempty measurable set that has no nonempty measurable proper subsets. The measurable space is *atomic* if every point lies in an atom.

Every countably generated measurable space is atomic. An example of a measurable space that is not atomic is $\{0,1\}^\kappa$ endowed with the product $\sigma$-algebra for $\kappa$ uncountable.

For countably generated measurable spaces endowed with a probability measure $\mu$, the measure $\mu$ is atomless if and only if $\mu(A)$ for every atom $A$. The assumption that the space is countably generated can not be weakened to it being atomic. To see this, endow $\mathbb{R}$ with the countable-cocountable $\sigma$-algebra and the probability measure $\mu$ that assigns probability $1$ to uncountable sets and probability $0$ to countable sets. Then $\mu$ is atomic but the atoms of the $\sigma$-algebra, the singletons, have all measure zero.

Proofs of these statements can be found in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/117006/21674) of mine. A great reference for these issues is the booklet *Borel Spaces* by Rao and Rao.

Comment: You said the measurable space is atomic if every point lies in an atom. But by defining for every $\omega$ the set $\mathfrak a(\omega)$ as the set of all $\omega'$ which cannot be separated from $\omega$ by a measurable set, you will end up that every $\omega$ is contained in an atom, not? So every measurable space is atomic??

Comment: @AndyTeich No., $\mathfrak a(\omega)$ may not be measurable.