# Confused about the definitions of atom

Tags: measure-theory, definition

I went though half a dozen books on measure theory, and it occurs to me that the definition of [atom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28measure_theory%29) is not particularly unified.

> Version $1$: A set $E$ in a $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ is called atom, if there is no proper subset $F\subsetneq E$ such that $F \in \Sigma$.

Alternately:

> Version $2$: Let $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space. A set $E ∈ Σ$ is an atom if $\mu(E) > 0$ and whenever $F ∈ Σ, F ⊆ E$ then $\mu(F) = 0$ or $\mu(E \setminus F) = 0$.

The definitions don't seem to be equivalent at least because the first one doesn't even mention measure.

So how should we understand them?

**EDIT**:

Here is what I've found on MO in the comments to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22477/sigma-algebra-without-atoms):

Pete L. Clark asks:

> I know what an atom is in a measure space. What is the definition of an atom in a sigma algebra?

Jonas Meyer responds:

> I think it's a nonempty element of the sigma algebra whose only proper subset in the sigma algebra is $∅$.

So the definitions seem to be about different objects. Are they even connected is some way? Does one of them imply another?

Comment: Related (may be of interest, I don't know exactly if it is to be considered a duplicate): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41142/questions-on-atoms-of-a-measure?rq=1

Comment: @rubik: I have seen the question yet both definitions there have $\mu$ unlike the first one in my question.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, an atom is a kind of set.

In the first case, an atom is a set in a σ-algebra with a certain property with respect to the σ-algebra. Call this atom_1.

In the second case, an atom is a set in the σ-algebra of a measure with a certain property with respect to the measure. Call this atom_2.

atom_1 is a pointwise concept and doesn't involve a measure. atom_2 is looser because it's still true after modifying by a set of measure zero.

In any case, the two concepts are similar in structure, and can be compared.

Here is a relationship that is easy to see:

An atom_1 in a σ-algebra is necessarily an atom_2 for any measure μ defined on the σ-algebra (provided the atom_1 has positive μ-measure).

But the converse is false because if you add a nonempty set of μ-measure zero to an atom_1 of positive μ-measure it stops being an atom_1 but remains an atom_2.

An atom_1 of zero μ-measure is not an atom_2.